# Multivariable Maximum and Minimum Problem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

> Let $f(x, y) = 2xye^{-x^2-y^2}.$ Find critical points. Use second derivative to to determine whether a critical point corresponds to local min, max or saddle.

Hi so for this question I am able to get my critical points by taking all the partial derivatives but when I get to inputting my critical points into the equation $f_{xx}f_{yy}-(f_{xy})^2$. I don't get the right answer. For instance one of the critical points is $(0, 0)$ but when I input it into the equation I get $0$ which is not correct as it is supposed to be $-4$. Can someone show me how to use the second derivative for this question.

EDIT: I took the partial derivatives to get
Fxx= 4(2x^2-3)xye^(-x^2-y^2)
Fyy = 4(2y^2-3)xye^(-x^2-y^2)
Fxy = 2(2y^2-1)xe^(-x^2-y^2)

D(x, y) = fxx*fyy - (fxy)^2

Therefore, whenever I put the required equations in and set them to 0 I do not get the answer expected which is -4.

Comment: Please edit your post to include your work. Otherwise we have to be mind readers to figure out why you don't get the right answer.

Comment: The question has been EDITED I included the partial derivatives and the formula used to check what D(x, y) is equal to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value for $f_{xy}$ cannot be correct, as $x$ and $y$ do not appear symmetrically in it. (Note that $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$, so everything should be symmetric.) Indeed, 
$$f_{xy} = 2(2x^2-1)(2y^2-1)e^{-(x^2+y^2)},$$
so $f_{xy}(0,0) = 2$.